# what is the difference between stochastic equation and heat equation?

Tags: heat-equation, stochastic-pde

I understand the heat equation would be $$\partial_{t}f(x,t)=\partial_{xx}f(x,t)$$ I would like to know how will I write  a stochastic heat equation?

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10473-019-0315-2.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.07604.pdf

Comment: i want to know the precise equation for a "stochastic heat equation" and "heat equation'. Will i be write to represent the stochastic equation as $$u_{t}=u_{xx} +p(t)$$ where $p(t)$ is white noise or its the same as the heat equation?